# Not able to connect Bing Maps API with Power Apps

Tags: swagger, bing-maps, powerapps

We need to get Bing Maps to one of our apps in Power Apps.  Whenever we enter a URL of the format on Power Apps [http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/imagerySet/centerPoint/zoomLevel?mapSize=mapSize&pushpin=pushpin&mapLayer=mapLayer&format=format&mapMetadata=mapMetadata&key=BingMapsKey](http://mapLayer=mapLayer&format=format&mapMetadata=mapMetadata&key=BingMapsKey), we get an error stating that the Swagger file cannot be found. We tried enter the URL by going to **Connections->Manage Custom Connector-> Create Custom Connector->Use an OpenAPI Url**
[image]
So far we've tried connecting several Bing Map API endpoints, we've read through the docs and are unable to find a Swagger definition file on Bing's API. Do we have to create our own Swagger for this API and is there a template we can follow?

Answer (score 1):

Passing in the URL you provided won't work as it returns an error. You would need to pass in a URL that returns a response. That said, the response structure of Bing Maps REST services is very complicated and you would need to use several different requests to see the full response object. There is no single way to return the complete JSON structure of the REST services as they vary depending on which end point you use. The Bing Maps REST Service JSON schema is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870778.aspx

That said, if you are using .NET, take a look at the official .NET library for the Bing Maps REST services: https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit/